# fscanf: how to read but not assign commas?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a C program that reads in a list of values separated by commas from a .txt file and assigns the values to variables. I want to assign the first value to a string, the second to an int, the third to a double and the fourth to a double. However, the entire line gets assigned to the string, and the rest are garbage or random values. I want to be able to "skip over" the commas and read assign values between the commas. The final double has a percentage sign at the end so I read the value using a %%, at least thats what I believe should be done.

```
fscanf(text_file, "%s,%d,%lf,%lf%%%[^\n]", title, &count, &size, &percentage);
```

A data point would look like this:
yellow-leaves,43,4.50,9.00%
But the values of title contain the entire line, and the rest of the values are just random garbage values.

Comment: Better to read all the line with `fgets()` first and then use `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that `scanf()` is ill-suited for user-input.

Anyway ... `"%s"` reads commas (it skips whitespace), try `"%[^,]"`.

```
// assuming
// char title[99];
if (fscanf(f, " %98[^,],%d...", title, ...) != 4) /* error */;
//             ^ skip whitespace
```

Better yet: read a whole line with `fgets()` then parse it, possibly with `sscanf()`.

```
char buff[999];
while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, f)) {
    // parse buff
}
```